# lme4: how are "non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!" actually modeled?

Tags: r, binomial-distribution, lme4-nlme, weighted-data

So I get the non-integer #successes in a binomial glm! warning, which has been asked about many times and I understand what it is. My dv is a % measure of accuracy, and these have weights so that they can be modeled using glmer(family=binomial). Sometimes however, people received fractional scores-- so although it is correct to think of  them having 5 trials, they might have earned a 0.9 when the weights say it is 5, because they were awarded 4.5/5 as correct. Hence the non-integer successes.

Of course R only gives you a warning here, the models converge and the results look sensible. If I round up or down (to 4/5 or 5/5) to force the data to have only integer successes, the estimates change only slightly-- so it's clear to me that whatever R does with these non-integer successes, it isn't crazy.

However I'm now super worried about understanding WHAT it does with these non-integer successes, and why the warning is there if the estimates seem fine... do I need to be doing something else to model these data even though the results look valid?

Comment: The very last question is a statistical question, & so on topic, IMO.

Comment: I did answer this on `r-sig-mixed-models` ...